# Complex mySQL Two Table Query

Tags: mysql, subquery, inner-join

I have two tables shown below

Table 1

```
ID  username  
1   johndoe  
2   mikeb
```

Table 2

```
ID  user_id     meta_key    meta_value  
23      1       my_pin      12345  
24      2       my_pin      67890
```

I'm trying to write a mySQL query that will return

```
ID   username    my_pin  
 1   johndoe     12345  
 2   mikeb       67890
```

My approach is to use a subquery, but its not working.

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    (SELECT meta_value 
     FROM table1 
     WHERE meta_key = "my_pin"
       AND table1.ID = table2.user_id) as my_pin 
FROM 
    table1
INNER JOIN 
    table2 ON table1.ID = table2.user_id
```

This fails because the subquery returns multiple rows. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**Edit**: additional info

In an effort to simplify my question, I left out a few details (sorry).
Table 2 has multiple entries

Table 2

```
ID  user_id     meta_key    meta_value  
23      1       my_pin      12345  
24      2       my_pin      67890 
25      1       my_id       10011
26      2       my_id       10012
```

I need the query to return

```
ID   username    my_pin  my_id
 1   johndoe     12345   10011
 2   mikeb       67890   10012
```

So what should the WHERE clause look like if I use a "simple" join?

Comment: You just need a regular join.

Comment: This is one of the most basic JOINs, not a complex query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to those who responded. Here is what I came up with to address the updated issue.

```
    SELECT t1.ID, t1.username,
    (
    SELECT meta_value
          FROM t2.wp_usermeta
          WHERE meta_key = "my_id"
          AND user_id = t1.ID
    ) as my_id,
    (
    SELECT meta_value
          FROM t2.wp_usermeta
          WHERE meta_key = "my_pin"
          AND user_id = t1.ID
    ) as my_pin
    FROM table1 AS t1
    INNER JOIN table2 AS t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.user_id
    WHERE t2.meta_key = "my_pin"
```

Answer (score 0):

Joining both of the tables will give you all the information you need and you can use `WHERE` clause to select only the results you need.

```
SELECT ID, meta_value as my_pin
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
  ON table1.ID = table2.user_id
WHERE table2.meta_key = "my_pin"
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try"? Please explain to the OP (and future visitors to SO) why you did what you did.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Thank you for reminding me  to add explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

This is done with a simple `JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.username, t2.meta_value AS my_pin
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.ID = t2.user_id
WHERE t2.meta_key = "my_pin"
```

You could also do it by joining with a subquery:

```
SELECT t1.username, t2.meta_value AS my_pin
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN (SELECT user_id, meta_value
      FROM table2
      WHERE meta_key = "my_pin") AS t2
ON t1.ID = t2.user_id
```